# Will an "Excellent" throw give you a greater chance of capturing the Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Within Pokémon Go, when you throw a Pokéball at a Pokémon, you have the potential to get a **Nice**, **Great**, or **Excellent** throw. If you throw an excellent Pokéball on a challenging Pokémon (when their circle is orange or red), will this increase your chances of capturing the Pokémon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at many sources online and the research that others have done, making an "**Nice**", "**Great**", or "**Excellent**" throw ***does*** increase your chances of catching the Pokémon.

[Source 1](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics#6)

[Source 2](https://pokemongohub.net/capture-bonus-chart-for-pokemon-go/)

Looks like the throws bonuses are:

> **Nice Throw** - 1.15X bonus
>
> **Great Throw** - 1.5X bonus
>
> **Excellent Throw** - 1.85X bonus

Here is a [catch rate calculator](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catchcalc#/) so you can play with the odds yourself.

Answer (score 11):

Getting a "Nice", "Great", or "Excellent" throw is possible by getting the Pokeball to land inside the shrinking colored circle. This gets you bonus experience if you catch it with that throw. The size of the circle determines which one you get. (Approximately, full circle-66%=Nice, 66%-33%=Great, 33%-smallest circle=Excellent.)

So getting those special throws won't boost your catch chance directly but having the circle as small as possible will.

The [official FAQ](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221957648-Finding-and-Catching-wild-Pok%C3%A9mon) says:

> You have the greatest chance of capturing the Pokémon while the colored ring is at its smallest diameter.

Comment: @HunterTurner That is correct. From my experience and from what I've heard from others, the smaller the colored circle is when you hit it with the ball, the better chance you have to catch.

Comment: @HunterTurner Yes - and you could also feed it some berries (check your items) to increase the chances more

Comment: @GarrettJ The official FAQ says that exactly. "You have the greatest chance of capturing the Pokémon while the colored ring is at its smallest diameter."
https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221957648-Finding-and-Catching-wild-Pok%C3%A9mon

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe so. I have no concrete proof of this, and while a lot of people say this is true, I'm not convinced. What I've read is that the smaller the inner circle the higher the catch rate, but in my experience it has no meaning other than the opportunity to get extra xp from the nice/great/excellent throw. I can't say for sure, as i get great/nice a lot more often than excellent, but i have had Pokemon escape and excellent throw, even with low CP and a green inner circle. That being said I still try to throw it when the circle is the smallest, maybe I'm just superstitious.

Comment: this literally contradicts the official FAQ