# How can I improve catch rates in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the original three Pokemon games, you could hold A + B + Down while tossing a Pokeball to increase the catch success rate. Since Pokemon Go is on mobile platforms, is there an equivalent combo for the touchscreen?

EDIT: As I have now been informed, my childhood belief was merely a placebo. But my question still stands, are there any strategies that can be used when attempting to catch a Pokemon to improve success rates?

Comment: A+B+Down is a placebo, it doesn't affect catch-rates on the original pokemon games at all.

Comment: @fcm LOL you just crushed so many childhoods

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) This A+B+Down was always a myth and never had any testing to back it up, it was all anecdotes and stories.

2) Not the way you ask, but there are items you can get at higher levels, specifically Razz Berries, that will calm a Pokemon and make it easier to catch. Also, throwing into the colored ring to get "nice," "great," or "excellent," throw will be slightly more effective. Throwing inside a smaller ring to get "great" or "excellent" throw, the more likely you are to successfully catch.
Additionally, throwing a curveball, where you drag the ball in a circle until it starts spinning before you throw it, will also improve the catch rate. While I don't have an exact amount for the increase, it feels like a rather dramatic increase in catch rate from anecdotal evidence.

Comment: The information in this answer conflicts with answers at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273862/will-an-excellent-throw-give-you-a-greater-chance-of-capturing-the-pokemon, where it is said that "nice", "great", "excellent" are only for the bonus and don't make the throw more effective.

Comment: There are also curve balls, which I have heard increase the catch rate.

Comment: @Draco18s That's right, added that information to the answer.

Comment: @Kadima It being like 3 years later now, [the math is known](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics). 0.7 * ball_catch_rate bonus for a curve ball. :P

Answer (score 7):

Yes. If you hold the pokeball down you'll see a ring on the pokemon go from large to small, if you wait until the ring is as small as possible to throw the ball, you will have a higher chance of catching the pokemon.